# TCP/IP Client Socket Program in C#.Net Using IP Address And Port Number

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, ip-address, tcp

TCP/IP Client Socket Program. Here My Main Requirement is Client Send Message and server receive message and store in database table in C#.Net, Using Server IP Address and Port Number.

Comment: Start from basics - http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-socket-programming.htm

Comment: I Need C# Console Application or C# Program if it is possible. In a Single Page client and server code. sending and receiving store in database table

Comment: Console application is not so different :) You can use same code set to do a console application. [Connection codes are similar]

Comment: Sorry.. This Below links are not working .not transfer data, & not received data. any another solution please.

Comment: change port number and try :)

Comment: Actually how we know local and server port numbers ..This is my local ip address 192.168.1.7 and This is my Server Ip Address 162.144.85.232

Comment: IP helps to identify YOU [servers, pc's and etc] in a network. PORT work in transport layer and help to differentiate currently running services in your end device. First try  to run client and server at local machine.

Comment: can i send my code to you.sending message command prompt halt. no respond means sending or receiving.

Answer (score 7):

You are talking about a simple Server-Client program.

What you need to do.

- Create a server program and run it first
- Create a client and connect to your running server using **Connect("SERVER IP", PORT)**
- Now when client is connected to server, receive message to server and use database connections to store that message in database

Guides :

- Write server -
  http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-server-socket.htm
- Write client -
  http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-client-socket.htm
- C# database access [SQL] -
  http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm

UPDATE - As requested and as a guidance here is a working client and a server

CLIENT-

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.IO;
    
    
    namespace socket_prog
    {
        class Client
        {
            private static void Main(String[] args)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[10];
    
                IPHostEntry iphostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                IPAddress ipAdress = iphostInfo.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAdress, 32000);
    
                Socket client = new Socket(ipAdress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    
                try
                {
                    client.Connect(ipEndpoint);
    
                    Console.WriteLine("Socket created to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    
                    byte[] sendmsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This is from Client\n");
    
                    int n = client.Send(sendmsg);
    
                    int m = client.Receive(data);
    
                    Console.WriteLine("" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
                    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    client.Close();
    
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
    
                Console.WriteLine("Transmission end.");
                Console.ReadKey();
    
            }
        }
    }
```

SERVER-

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace socket_prog
{
    class Server
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("From server\n");
            string data = null;

            IPHostEntry iphostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = iphostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 32000);

            ConsoleKeyInfo key;
            int count = 0;

            Socket sock = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


            sock.Bind(localEndpoint);
            sock.Listen(5);

            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("\nWaiting for clients..{0}", count);
                Socket confd = sock.Accept();

                int b = confd.Receive(buffer);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, b);

                Console.WriteLine("" + data);
                data = null;

                confd.Send(msg);

                Console.WriteLine("\n<< Continue 'y' , Exit 'e'>>");
                key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.KeyChar == 'e')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nExiting..Handled {0} clients", count);
                    confd.Close();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    break;
                }
                confd.Close();
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Run server first. Then run client.

Comment: it's working connection between client and server but how to send text .But Here text not send from client to server.my Requirement is client send request and server receive text and store database table. please help me next step.. Thanks KCdod..

Comment: Use my solution as a guide. Try to learn what happens first :)

Comment: Yes I'm using your solution,your code only client and server connected one and each.But how to send text like (Hii, Hello) messages from client to server. then server receive message. Here your code only connected between client and server only. not send text.

Comment: In my solution client send "This is from Client" to server. Server after receiving that sends "From server" to client.. You must start server first in one console. then start client in another console. it should work :)

Comment: Also server will ask whether to continue wait for clients :) .. btw you need two consoles applications to do this..

Comment: Ya i create two console applications one is server and one is client. connection bwn client and server connected, but text not send client to server. Please resolve this issue .thank you

Comment: Connection is not preserved here [in given example] . What these programs do is transmit simple two messages between client and server. Server sends "From server" text , client sends "This is from Client" text. Please dnt jst copy paste code. ! learn them

Comment: Okay . but i want transfer text from client to server with using IP Address and Port Number. and insert text in Database Table . If u have code please send to me. Thanks KCdod..

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa In my case Client is a `Pathology Machine` with a specific IP Address and Port. So it means I cannot create `Client`. So how can I receive data from the server? Is there any way to get data from the machine if I already know the IP Address and Port Number of the Machine? Please help.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi you just need to make sure you have network access from client to server. And the use specific IP addresses when defining IPAddress

Answer (score 1):

you can get help from this below mentioned link
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/socket-programming-in-C-Sharp/